# Firebase Child By AutoID with multiple users?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am using firebase for a messaging app. For the messages, I use a childByAutoID() to create the new message. If two people create a message at the same time, will the ID be created correctly?

```
 let messageConnection = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(convoID!).childByAutoId()
    messageConnection.updateChildValues(["content" : messageText ?? "incomplete", "sender": userHash, "time": time], withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in

    if error != nil{
        print("ERROR")
    }
    else{
        let conversationRef = Database.database().reference().child("conversations").child(self.convoID!)
        conversationRef.updateChildValues(["last_message" : messageText!,"last_message_time":time])
        textField.text = ""
    }

})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "correctly", but if you're worried about the order of the push IDs, they are generated using a timestamp, so messages will appear in the order they were created. They are also unique so no two message IDs will ever overlap.

Comment: @JenPerson thank you. My worry was that they would overwrite each other, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what "correctly" means to you here.

But when two app instances call `childByAutoId()` at the exact same time, they'll still get a unique ID. The IDs are statistically guaranteed to be unique, and include a sufficient number of random bits to ensure that.

To learn more about these push IDs, read [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).